# Issue Connecting two home networks

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I have a home networking question.

I have two DLINK wireless/wired routers in my house, connected to the Internet ISP. There are a 2 computers on each of the two networks.
**Network1**: has 192.168.0.0 (gateway) Valid IP'S range - 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.10, with COMP1 having a fixed IP of 162.168.0.1

**Network2**: has 192.168.0.100 (gateway) Valid IP'S range - 192.168.0.101 - 192.168.0.110
with COMP2 having a static IP of 162.168.0.101, a WIRELESS printer on 192.168.0.102

Both routers have a netmask of **255.255.255.0**

My need is to connect the two routers, so that I can 
Remote desktop for COMP1 to COMP2 and vice-versa, and 
COMP1 to connect to the wireless printer on Network2.

can anyone help to set this up so that the both networks can talk to each

Comment: How are the routers connected to each other?

Comment: [This link](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/routers/f/two_routers.htm) might help.

Comment: Why are you using two routers? Why not just use a switch to extend the network (since you are basically using router 2 as a switch anyway)?  If you actually want to set up two networks you'll want to use subnets, so for example network 1 will be 192.168.0 and network 2 will be 192.168.1, then you will have to setup routing tables to route between the subnets.

Comment: I am using 2 routers due to the way my house is wired for network. I have home run wired network to all my rooms from my basement where the internet connection comes in, thru fibre optic. There is no modem. The internet connection comes in to 8 port switch. So to secure my connections, I put one router, and routed 4 outputs to network switch. One of the non-routed connection goes to my Office den, and there I put the second router that has the COMP2 and the wireless printer. So you see why I have two routers

Comment: You'll want to set up subnets then, and allow traffic from 192.168.0 into 192.168.1 and vise versa.

Comment: I can change the IP on Network1 to 192.168.1.100. But how and where do I do the routes? BTW, I use Windows 7 Ultimate on both computers.

Comment: What tester is saying is true, however having separate sub nets in one house is over complicating something as simple as a home network. Can you remove the 8 port switch and swap it with a router? then put a switch immediately on the other side of the router. Having two routers means two nats and two hops, which is not good especially in a home network where the gear may not be as intelligent.

Comment: @Kyle - You're right about over complicating the situation, I am just pointing out one way to do it using 2 routers.  Personally I would have one router near the switch coming in and then switches after that.  If the OP could put his router before the 8 port switch, life would be nice and simple.

Comment: @tester101 Don't worry I was not saying you were wrong at all (you got +1). I was simply asking the OP to rethink his methods, if he must set it up as is then he should follow your suggestion.

Comment: @Kyle - No worries.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what you want to end up with.
[image: Network Topology]

Then you'll have to login to each router and allow traffic from the other subnet.  So from Router 1 you will allow traffic from 192.168.1, and from Router 2 you will allow traffic from 192.168.0.